# Best way to update android app without playstore update

Tags: android, user-interface, live, offline-caching

I have to build an app that can show a list of events e.g. cinema listings that will work either online and offline.  I need to know the best way to send updates to the list/array of events when a user is online without having to push updates in the google play store as they get added/updated daily

I am fairly new to this particular problem, I have made several apps in the past but they were purely informational updating once or twice a quarter or used webviews to online calendars (which isn't an option if the user needs to see a stored list when offline)

Ideally, I just need a way to check if there are any new events and store them in the array or update a textview if there is.

Comment: is your question is regarding app update or data update ?

Comment: @Swayangjit updating the data on the app e.g. contents of an array

Answer (score 1):

You will need a webservice for this. Call the API from your application to get upddated data from your server.

Comment: And this will data will be cached and accessible when the user is offline?

Comment: Yes, if you save the data either in your  sqlite database or use Realm database. See more here for realm https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: You can store that data in database for offline use.

Comment: if the answer helped you then pls upvote it. It gives motivation to help others also.

Comment: @PrashantSable upvoted! quick question, do you know of any tutorials on this?